# Target Audience prerequisite to enable on SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, audience-targeting

What is the prerequisite to enable target audience in SharePoint list 2010
because when i enable target audience in list settings it does not appear in edit item.

I find out that it relays on User Profile Service but when I create a new User Profile Service the web site will disappear with error

Comment: What error you are getting after creating the User profile service? what type of list you are trying to enable it? have you tried on content query webpart?

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps to enable Audience Targetting in Sharepoint List 2010 -

1. Click the list or library that contains the item you want to target.
2. On the list toolbar, click Settings, and then click List Settings or
   Document Library Settings.
3. Under General Settings, click Audience targeting settings.
4. Select the Enable audience targeting check box.

When you enable audience targeting on a list or library, you can target each item in the list or library to an audience.

NOTE: If the SharePoint list or library already is enabled for audience targeting, the Target Audiences column appears.

You should also check with the service which determines Target Audience should be enabled and running.

It's SharePoint User Profile Service that depends on "User Profile Synchronization Service". So first check the Services via Central Administration -> System Settings -> Manage Services on server.

Please refer below link to check with the configuration

http://geekswithblogs.net/venkatx5/archive/2010/11/25/how-to-do-enable-target-audience-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: i did that steps but target audience coloumn do not appear